# In Oracle SQL, what is a single pipe character ( '|' ) used for?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I was studying some dynamic SQL(or perhaps it was regular SQL ?) today in Oracle, when I saw the pipe char being used in a line like this:

```
someVar := 'someValue' | 'someOtherValue'
```

This puzzled me. Is it BITWISE-OR like in TSQL ? Or is it something else?  I am aware of the concatenation operator ( `||` )  , but it wasn't that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation only [shows it as a bitwise OR operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21642/express.htm#sthref264) in TimesTen:

> Bitwise OR of the two operands. 
>   Sets a bit to 1 if one or both of the corresponding bits in Expression1 and     Expression2 are 1. Sets a bit to 0 if both of the corresponding bits are 0.

But you didn't mention TimesTen, and it isn't valid in 'normal' SQL or PL/SQL.

Answer (score 5):

The `||` operator is used for concatenating two strings, in Oracle a single `|` is not a valid operator. Are you sure that the posted code actually *works*, and that is indeed running on an Oracle database?

Comment: Ah OK, got it. So you can use either `||` or single `|`  . thanks!